# Intermittent request handling slowness on Websphere 8.5.5 using CXF Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, websphere, cxf, stax

I have an application running on Websphere 8.5.5. Under high load a specific service usually takes 50ms to respond, but intermittently, all 4 balanced JVMs starts to take about 4 seconds to handle the requests. The problem persist for about 2 seconds and then response time goes back to normal.

It seems that the problem happens when the number of simultaneous users raises to a certain amount, but then the environment becomes able to handle the requests and the response time goes back to normal.

I can see that the slow method is:

```
createXMLStreamReader(InputStream, String)
```

From class **StaxUtils**

This method is calling the stack

```
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.waitForCompletion(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:359)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.getByteCount(AsyncFuture.java:218)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:215)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:182)
... 51 more
```

After some research I found some similar problems, but none of them seems to be exactly what I need.

[PM21874: A JAX-WS client might fail with an asynchronous timeout error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM21874)

[Intermittent WSI transport error when searching for or creating work items](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21688212)

Comment: Do you have GC issues?

Comment: After the problem there is a small GC Caused suspension time on 2 JVMs, but during the problem there isn't any GC issue. The memory utilization is below 60%.